# Flatpickr AlpineJS Persist Plugin on Dange Range Selection

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, session-storage, persist, flatpickr

I have a perfectly working Flatpickr Date Range calendar that stores the dates in session storage. Here is my code:

```
<div
    x-data="{
        chosenDates: sessionStorage.getItem('_x_range'),
        value: [],
        init() {
            let picker = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
                mode: 'range',
                inline: false,
                dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
                showMonths: 2,

            })

            this.$watch('value', () => picker.setDate(this.value))
        },
    }"
>
    <div class="flex items-center flex-1 gap-2 overflow-hidden border border-gray-500 rounded-lg">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="ml-4 bi bi-calendar-event-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M4 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v1h16V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1V.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H4zM16 14V5H0v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2m-3.5-7h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5"/>
        </svg>
        <input id="rangeValue" :value="chosenDates" placeholder="Add dates"   x-ref="picker" type="text" class="p-0 py-4 placeholder-gray-600 border-0 bg-none focus:ring-0 " data-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set item:

```js
function dateRange() {
    var date = document.getElementById("rangeValue").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("_x_range", date);
    sessionStorage.setItem("start", start);
    sessionStorage.setItem("end", end);
    const start = sessionStorage.getItem("start");
}
$('#rangeValue').on('focus', ({ currentTarget }) => $(currentTarget).blur())
$("#rangeValue").prop('readonly', false)
```

Receive item:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem("_x_range") != null) {
    document.getElementById("chosenRange").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("_x_range");
    document.getElementById("rangeValue").value = sessionStorage.getItem("_x_range");
}
```

If possible, I would like to learn how to set this up using AplineJS and Persist instead, in order to not overdue it with too much code.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
<div x-data="{
                    thePicker: null,

                    chosenDates: $persist([]).using(sessionStorage).as('_x_range'),

                    init() {
                        this.thePicker = flatpickr(this.$refs.picker, {
                            mode: 'range',
                            inline: false,
                            dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
                            showMonths: 2,
                            defaultDate: this.chosenDates,
                            onChange: (selectedDates) => {this.chosenDates = [...selectedDates];}
                        });
                    },
                }"
>

    <div class="flex items-center flex-1 gap-2 overflow-hidden border border-gray-500 rounded-lg">

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="ml-4 bi bi-calendar-event-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M4 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v1h16V3a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1V.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0V1H4zM16 14V5H0v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2m-3.5-7h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5"/>
        </svg>

        <input type="text"
               x-ref="picker"
               placeholder="Add dates"
               class="p-0 py-4 placeholder-gray-600 border-0 bg-none focus:ring-0"
        >

        <span title="Clear"
              class="text-blue-600 cursor-pointer"
              @click="thePicker.clear()"
        >
            X
        </span>

    </div>

    <div x-text="chosenDates"> </div>

</div>
```

The date range is stored in the Alpine *chosenDates* variable, which is persisted via *Persist* and initialized to an empty array.
When the datepicker is initialized, the *chosenDates* variable is used to fill the *defaultDate* parameter.
When a date range is selected, *flatpicker* fires the *onChage* event, so I used that to copy the new range into the *chosenDates* variable.
I added a *"clear"* button to reset the input field in the *flatpicker* way, calling the *clear()* method (it's a simple example), then I had to store the *flatpicker* reference in *thePicker* variable .
I also added a <div> to show the contents of *choosenDates* via *x-text*

No other Javascript is needed.

Comment: That's great, working so far. I will need to do some research on how to modify the session storage date as it's outputting session storage in ISO format. Thank you!

Comment: Got it all figured out. Thanks again. Finally getting back into AlpineJS after a long break and I love how far it has come. I have a lot to learn.